# Using Numpy to get an average of an array within a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

```
columnFour = [data[0::, 1] == 1, data[0::, 4]]
```

The data is a table, with 1 being the variable I'm selecting for (where it equals 1), and 4 the variable I'm trying to draw out into an array of one dimension.

Some of the values in the 4 column are blank (''), and the error I'm getting from python is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<filename>", line 62, in <module>
  print np.mean(age, dtype=float);
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2373, in mean
  return _wrapit(a, 'mean', axis, dtype, out)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
  result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 235, in asarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence
```

How can I either select all the non-null numbers in column 4, or select all including those nulls? I would prefer to select all, but either would work. I'm trying to come up with an average of the data in column 4 to reinsert into the null values, but averaging them across different column 1 values.

For example all the numbers in column 4 where `column 1 == 1` would get averaged, and then the nulls where `column 1 == 1` would get that average re-inserted.

EDIT:
I used a for loop to just go through the data.

for x in data:
    if x[1] == '1' and x[4]:
        first.append(np.float(x[4]))
    if x[1] == '2' and x[4]:
        second.append(np.float(x[4]))
    if x[1] == '3' and x[4]:
        third.append(np.float(x[4]))

The result is three arrays that have the different values I was looking for, and can then be averaged and put back into the holes in the data.

Comment: What kind of array is `data`? An object array? It seems to have both numbers and strings. Or is it all strings?

Comment: columnFour = [data[0::, 1] == 1, data[0::, 4]]


This line does not make a lot of sense.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

>The data is a table, with 1 being the variable I'm selecting for (where it equals 1), and 4 the variable I'm trying to draw out into an array of one dimension.


Can you try to explain this more clearly?

Comment: the data is a table of numbers and strings, but both columns I'm trying to process are numbers.

The list comprehension is bad, I know.

   I want to choose all the numbers in column 4, where column 1 == 1. 
   I want the result to be an array where in each columnFour[x][1] the number is one, and in each columnFour[x][4] the number is whatever it was in that row in the data array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
mask = data[:, 1] == 1
average = np.mean(data[mask, 4])
```

There is no list comprehension in the code you've provided, you just create a list with two elements, the first `data[:, 1] == 1` and the second `data[:, 4]`.

Comment: I'm going to keep working on this, but the first line of your answer returns the boolean result of the '==' on the first row.

Comment: yes mask is a boolean array, the result of the `==` comparison, which I use on the second line to index data.